# Volume key (fn +f7/f8) doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have the Notebook Samsung 759XDA with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and Windows 11.
In my keyboard I can press `Fn` + `F7` to decrease volume and `Fn` + `F8` to increase the volume.
On Windows keys works correctly while on Ubuntu they have a strange behavior.

When I press `Fn` + `F7` once, the volume is brought to zero as if the keys were still being pressed. The combination to increase the volume has the same behavior, it increases the volume to the maximum as if the keys remain pressed even if they have been pressed only once. After pressing these two combinations for about 3-4 times then they no longer work and even pressing them the volume remains exactly at the same level.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I say this to people often: forgive the copy-paste answer. I suggest upgrading the system firmware to the latest available version. It is not by any means guaranteed to help, but can't hurt (unless you do it wrong!).